# What do some DC motors smell of when running?

Tags: dc-motor

Some DC motors have a characteristic smell when they run, and today I started wondering what it would be. I noticed it many years ago for some train scale models (probably Märklin), some years later on my father's power drill (handheld, AC powered). Back then I assumed it had something to do with the sparks in there. Now my brushless (and sparkless) cordless drill, a Bosch GSB 10,8, has the same smell when running; another one, DRC 18/4 from Festool, much less so.

The smell is hard to describe, it is not something like a solvent or grease or something that is melting. I’d also say it is strongest for the first few seconds after some idle days.

Comment: Burning dust, most likely.

Comment: Does it perhaps smell like a that rainy day smell? If so, that's smell of ozone generated by sparks in the air.

Comment: It sounds like the lubrication used in the unit, oil or grease.

Comment: @DKNguyen ozone is the answer combined with hot varnish on the coils.

Comment: I'm with @DDuck and the hot varnish.

Comment: @DKNguyen In the region I live, rainy days do not have a particular smell, so it is hard to tell. Also, I cannot see sparks in the brushless engine (and as of my understanding there should not be any unless something goes wrong with the motor control) :)

Comment: @Gil That would explain the smell being strongest on cold start.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster You don't need to be able to see the sparks. Ozone smells has a chemical, clear, transparent smell I guess. Not like a hydrocarbon, grease, burnt plastic, or paint.

Comment: A beleive brushless does not normally have sparks or an arc of any type to generate Ozone.